# Function to compare a validation message to a fixed message

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am writing a function in HP UFT to compare a validation message in my application to a fixed message. Can anyone help me with the function?

Please point out errors in my code and help me improve it.

So far I have written this:

```
Sub fnCaptureTextandCompare(objPage,oWebElement,ObjectName)

    If objPage.WebElement(oWebElement).Exist(10) Then
        strActualError = objPage.WebElement(oWebElement).getroproperty("innertext")
        strExpectedError = DataTable.Value(Parameter1,"Data")
        Call fnCompare(strExpectedError,strActualError,ObjectName)      
    Else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"fnCaptureTextandCompare","Webelement '"&ObjectName&"' does not exist" 
    End if
End Sub

Sub fnCompare(Expected_Value,Actual_Value,FieldName)

        If Expected_Value = Actual_Value Then
            Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"fnCompare:","Field:'"&FieldName&vbcrlf&" Expected= '"&Expected_Value&"'"&vbcrlf&"Actual= '"&Actual_Value&"'"
        Else
            Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"fnCompare:","Field:'"&FieldName&vbcrlf&" Expected= '"&Expected_Value&"'"&vbcrlf&"Actual= '"&Actual_Value&"'"
        End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give any error to you??.. It looks ok superficially.. your objPage has reference to both browser and page hopefully..

Comment: Yes the error is on this line:
 strExpectedError = DataTable.Value(Parameter1,"Data")
The error is " Specify the parameter using a text string or numerical index value."

Btw this Parameter and data is on an excel file that I am using as my database from where it is reading the values etc.

Comment: That error is because you are just writing Paramter1 in value. DataTable.value takes 2 parameters, column name(which should be in string format) or column Number(which should be in integer format and Sheet name(String) or SheetID(integer). Correct syntax is DataTable.value("Parameter1","Data") provided there is a column named as Parameter1 in the excel that you have imported in DataTable and the sheet name in DataTable is "Data"

Comment: Please Refer http://qtp.blogspot.in/2009/03/qtp-reading-from-datatable.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_data_table_methods.htm to know how to retrieve value from datatable